# Entity context lifetime with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, mysql-connector

I am new to the Entity Framework 4. I've done a bit of playing around with SQL Server, and MySQL. I ran into a problem using MySQL in regards to lazy loading, and I believe is that the MySQL connector doesn't allow multiple queries on the same connection - it must be closed first.

I would like to run a query, store a reference to the results in a field of my class, and then later on, modify/save it or load related data. However, the context has gone out of scope and been disposed of.

```
class MyClass {
    List<AThing> _stuff;

    private void ReadStuff() {
        using (var context = new MyEntities()) {
            _stuff = context.TableOfStuff.ToList();
        }
    }

    // Stuff is used by other methods, bound to controls, etc.
}
```

So, does `Stuff` exist without a context? From what I understand, the context is what does change tracking and the like... Once `ToList()` is called, my context is useless for another query.

Must I avoid this? Is there a better way of accomplishing this? Am I wrong above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. When `context` goes out of scope the items in the list are no longer attached. If you change them you can `Attach` them to a new context. But there are other ways depening on what you want to do and how you want to do it.

Calling `ToList` materializes your query but won't leave an open `DataReader`. So you should be able to execute multiple queries.

Comment: I'll give this a shot when I'm able. I didn't know you could reattach entities back to a context. Thanks!